# Combine two SQL queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, expression

Please forgive me if this appears a bit vague and if my terminologies are incorrect. I'm an associate/junior level network engineer with very limited SQL querying experience. With that aside here is what I'm dealing with;

I'm trying to create a filter in Goldmine (CMS/CRM) that filters results by the variables specified below.

```
WHERE c1.U_COMPANY > ' ' AND  c1.U_CONTACT > ' ' AND  
     (c1.U_COUNTRY <> 'SOUTH AFRICA') AND  
     (c1.U_CONTACT NOT LIKE '%MANAGER%' OR c1.U_CONTACT IS NULL) AND     
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%ARCHIVE%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL) AND 
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%DOCUMENT%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL) AND 
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%SUPPLIER%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL) AND  
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%OTHER%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL) AND
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%TENANT%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL)
```

I need to incorporate the following but have no idea where it is safe to the expression to the above.

```
SELECT C1.*
FROM FMBSM.DBO.CONTACT1 C1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNTNO
    FROM FMBSM.DBO.CONTSUPP
    WHERE (
            CONTSUPP.RECTYPE = 'P'
            AND CONTSUPP.CONTACT = 'E-mail Address'
            )
    ) CS
    ON CS.AccountNo = C1.AccountNo
ORDER BY C1.CONTACT
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Thanks for neatening the code MiguelH

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean but a valid statement starts with your `SELECT` part (excluding the `ORDER BY C1.Contact`), then you put all of your `WHERE` part in then you put the `ORDER BY C1.Contact` part at the end. What tool are you running this statement in?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Radu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be fine to put it at the end, before the `ORDER BY`, where a `WHERE` clause is normally placed:

```
SELECT C1.*
FROM FMBSM.DBO.CONTACT1 C1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNTNO
    FROM FMBSM.DBO.CONTSUPP
    WHERE (
            CONTSUPP.RECTYPE = 'P'
            AND CONTSUPP.CONTACT = 'E-mail Address'
            )
    ) CS
    ON CS.AccountNo = C1.AccountNo
WHERE c1.U_COMPANY > ' ' AND  c1.U_CONTACT > ' ' AND  
     (c1.U_COUNTRY <> 'SOUTH AFRICA') AND  
     (c1.U_CONTACT NOT LIKE '%MANAGER%' OR c1.U_CONTACT IS NULL) AND     
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%ARCHIVE%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL) AND 
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%DOCUMENT%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL) AND 
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%SUPPLIER%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL) AND  
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%OTHER%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL) AND
     (c1.U_KEY1 NOT LIKE '%TENANT%' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL)
ORDER BY C1.CONTACT
```

Comment: Radu, with every morsel and fiber in my bones and body, thank you kindly Sir.
I will study this and make sure I know and understand it for the future.
Much appreciated.

Comment: @Absurd_Introspective This is basic SQL syntax. You can take a look here to have [a quick read about these concepts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).